# Where is the reference to explain the SSMS Object Explorer icons?

Tags: ssms

(This is **not** the same as the two questions asking about a blue circle with white question mark).

The Object Explorer in SQL Server Management Studio can show **many** different kinds of icons. Where on earth is the documentation to explain them? (Even the other questions on here about the blue circle and white question mark don't point to any references from Microsoft, and various answers simply give various ways to "get rid of" the icon and the only answer that explains the meaning says "I think it means..." This is very poor on Microsoft's part. Why not provide context help in a pop-up when you hover over the icons?)

Below is a variety of icons I can find without trying too hard.

[image: SQL Server Management Studio SSMS node icons]

To put the image words into parsable text:

- green circle with a white triangle facing right (eg. database engine)
- green circle with a white triangle facing right, preceded by a black x (eg. sql server agent)
- green circle with a white triangle facing right, preceded by a black arrow pointing right (eg. distributed transactions coordinator, under management)
- red x at top right (data collection, under management)
- red x preceded by a black cube (resource governor, under management)
- black square with lower half filled black and upper half white (policy management, under management)
- two blue arrows, one facing left, the other facing right (availability group)
- two blue arrows forming a circle (availability group replica)
- red circle with white square, preceded by a black x (sql server agent, with service disabled)
- red x (agent job, disabled)

I mean some of these I can guess - but where on earth is the full list of possible icons documented?

(It's the two blue arrows forming a circle on the availability group replica that got me searching just now).